# Getting error using Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin with ionic and angular js running on Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, angularjs, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

**Requirement:**

I am trying to build a mobile app using Ionic, Apache Cordova, Angular Js and Parse. One of the functionalities of the app is- it is suppose to let user login using Facebook (either using native app or browser based login). User will click 'Login with Facebook' button on the 'Sign In' page and that is suppose to open either the native Facebook app (if installed) or browser to redirect to Facebook login page for authentication. Once authenticated user should be able to perform further actions within the app.

**Issue:**
I am getting the following error on clicking 'Login with Facebook' button in my app within Xcode simulator.

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: facebookConnectPlugin

[image]

**What I have done so far?**

1) Created necessary HTML files with login button, angular js controllers and services for authentication flow.

2) Followed the instructions mentioned in the link below for Facebook authentication part.

[https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework/)

3) Based on the above article, cloned the plugin to the local directory and then installed the plugin to the app directory using cordova command. 
As per the article, I got the plugin from this git URL.
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

4) Plugin installation seems successful. Didn't see any errors on the Terminal. I can also see the plugin folder but it seem to have a folder with name 'phonegap-facebook-plugin' instead of com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect. See comments in the above article if you couldn't figure out what I mean. Not sure if this has anything to do with my issue.

5) Build the application using ionic build ios command.

6) Opened the xcodeproj inside platforms/ios folder in Xcode and ran the application on Xcode simulator.

7) When I click on 'Login with Facebook' button, I am getting 'Can't find variable: facebookConnectPlugin' as mentioned in the issue section above.

8) Added following code in the run method in app.js.I have removed the actual parseid, fbids from below code for the sake of this post.

```
myApp.run(function ($ionicPlatform,$rootScope,$state) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
        Parse.initialize("parseappid", "parsejskey");
        if (!(ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isAndroid())) {
            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
                    appId: 'fbappid',
                    version: 'v2.5',
                    xfbml: true
                });
            };

            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                    return;
                }
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        }          

    });
```

9) Added the following after body in index.html file.

<div id="fb-root"></div>

10) I even tried to manually add reference to facebookConnectPlugin.js (that was installed as a part of plugin installation)  by copying this js file from plugin directory into my js directory (www\js) as some articles suggested in the internet but nothing seem to make it work.

**Confusions I have?**

1) Do I also need to reference cordova.js in my index.html? I have only referenced ng-cordova.js.
2) Is facebookConnectPlugin suppose to work in Xcode simulator?

**Dev Environment I am using**

Mac OS X Yesomite, Visual Studio Code, Safari/Chrome, Xcode (v7.1.1)
Mostly testing using Xcode simulator & from Safari Develop

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck in a similar situation , but I can redirect the user to the login page.
I don't know if this helps you but you take a look.

See [Google Firebase: Handle the social login](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/social-login-with-ionic_77.html)  for further details on this.

I know it's from the guys of Firebase but there is one very important sentence in this article:

> The best way to build a hybrid app is to deal with the underlying details of Cordova as little as possible. For this, Ionic is your best friend. Ionic abstracts the difficult parts of hybrid development into an easy to use SDK.
>   But, there still is one area of difficulty. Social login. Logging in with a social provider requires a popup or a redirect. The problem is, this doesn’t exist in the native world. It’s okay though, there’s another way, and it’s easy.

And the "easy way" is to handle the flow manually:
[Facebook: Handling the login flow manually](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow)

I hope this helps you somehow even though you are using a social login plugin and I don't.

**Note:** Are you using an inapp-browser?.

Hope this helps